# Structs in C++ versus class

Tags: c++

What is the advantage of using a `struct` in C++ when you have `class`? I cannot find any literature on the subject. I have been told to just use class and is the correct

Comment: None, there is no real difference, it is purely a matter of convention, but you might get flooded by answers suggesting otherwise :-)

Comment: Have you considered investigating the difference between structs and classes in C++ and drawing your own conclusions?

Comment: The only difference is that with `class`, members are made private automatically whereas with `struct` they are public (before specifying any of `public:`, `private:`, `protected:` that is).

Comment: @AnotherTest Sigh. No, that is not the *only* difference. This always happens when this question gets asked.

Comment: @juanchopanza then what are the other differences

Comment: @AnotherTest It is explained in the duplicate.

Comment: @juanchopanza link is gone, but I see: difference in derived types as well. Thanks, didn't know about this.

Comment: @AnotherTest You can find the link at the top of the question now. It is worth a read, if only because there are many out there who have the impression you cannot do as much with `struct` as with `class`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Unfortunately the _other differences_ aren't explained in the accepted answer of the dupe, but in the second highvoted one.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually, the accepted answer *does* mention it, "that structs have default public members and **bases**", and the answer you refer to gets that part wrong (or at least, is not clear enough), and then talks about a "real difference" that is just down to convention. It is a very bad answer!

Comment: @juanchopanza THX for enlightening, didn't spot that at the 1st glance.